# High School Trigonometry Problem (I'm ashamed)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Hello, StackExchange community! I was helping a high school student with his math homework and very embarrassingly, I couldn't solve this problem.

The first triangle is the problem as drawn in the book. l, b, and t are given and one is supposed to calculate the value of $\alpha$. Edit: I probably should mention that this is an Isosceles triangle.

I have edited the second triangle and added some auxiliary stuff. Since the problem is about trigonometry, I've constructed a right angle, added x, y, and z. From here, I could use Pythagorean theorem to create a linear equation system with 3 variables (x, y, and z). Finally, with either one of the values of x, y or z I could use trigonometry to calculate $\alpha$.

I'm pretty sure my method will work, however, I'm not sure whether this is the wanted solution because it's very time-consuming and too complex for high school level math.

Anyway, I'd be happy if someone could share an easy solution for this.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: $$ l = \frac{b}{2\cos\alpha} + \frac{t}{\sin\alpha} $$ can you prove it and solve it with respect to $\alpha$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, I get it now ... I feel so stupid. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Except that it's a quartic in $\sin\alpha$, and if this is a high school problem it probably shouldn't involve anything beyond cubics.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: no, I was wrong, it is a quartic in $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}$ too, it boils down to solving $$ t + b u - 2 l u + b u^3 + 2 l u^3 - t u^4 = 0 $$ with respect to $u$.